# Running for loop on array from localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I am creating and storing an array in `localStorage`, and I would like to use a `for` loop to parse the array into separate `divs` within a container. Here's what I have so far:

```js
var arr = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];
window.localStorage.setItem('myArr', JSON.stringify(arr));

function populateContainer() {
  var newArr = window.localStorage.getItem('myArr');
  $('.container').html('');
  
  for (var i = 0, len = newArr.length; i < len; i++) {
    $('.container').append('<div>' + newArr[i] + '</div>');
  }
}
populateContainer();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Unfortunately what this is doing is creating a separate `div` for each individual character of the array items, so I am ending up with 18 `divs` with one character each instead of 3 `divs` with the 3 array items. Sorry the snippet isn't working, apparently SO doesn't support `localStorage`?

Comment: You will have to do JSON.parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing the JSON in `localStorage` correctly, but you also need to `parse()` it back when you retrieve it:

```
var arr = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('myArr'));
```

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/1beg0wod/)

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the JSON again when looping through it, as you saved the array as a string:

```js
var arr = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];
window.localStorage.setItem('myArr', JSON.stringify(arr));

function populateContainer() {
  var arr = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('myArr'));
  $('.container').html('');

  for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
    $('.container').append('<div>' + arr[i] + '</div>');
  }
}
populateContainer();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

JSFiddle since localStorage doesn't work here: https://jsfiddle.net/45h3fn0a/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) to store your data, you will have to use [`JSON.parse()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) to get it back into an array like so:

---

```js
var arr = ['item 1', 'item 2', 'item 3'];
window.localStorage.setItem('myArr', JSON.stringify(arr));

function populateContainer() {
  var newArr = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('myArr'));
  $('.container').html('');
  
  for (var i = 0, len = newArr.length; i < len; i++) {
    $('.container').append('<div>' + newArr[i] + '</div>');
  }
}
populateContainer();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```